# Как перевести название приложения в админке Django

Tags: django, django-admin

Я понимаю, что такой вопрос неоднократно задавался, даже есть уже похожий пост на stackoverflow [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19168671/how-to-translate-the-application-name-in-django-cms-admin). Я следую шагам, что там описаны - и ничего не получается. Мне не нужно делать файл переводов. Это слишком громоздко для меня в данной ситуации. Я хотел бы тупо захардкодить название приложения на русском.

Итак, мое приложение называется Questions. Хочу, чтоб лейбл был Вопросы  если я определяю в моделе в Meta классе verbose_name='Вопросы', то почему то вижу в админке 'Вопросыs'. Что происходит, откуда тут эта буква? Если я определяю в файле apps.py в классе конфигурации verbose_name, то вообще результата нет. Файл перевода пробовал делать. Тоже не работало. Посредник перевода django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware подключил.

Коллеги, может кто-нибудь описать порядок действий, чтоб приложение Questions стало не 'Questions' в админке, а 'Вопросы'?

Comment: Для начала определитесь, что вы переводите-то — название приложения или модели? Это две разных вещи, они переводятся по-разному и это два отдельных не связанных вопроса

Comment: Да, действительно, не внимательно посмотрел. Там выводится название модели и приложения. Поискал, теперь понятно, как это связано. Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В файле `__init__.py` приложения

```
default_app_config = 'questions.apps.QuestionsConfig'
```

В apps.py

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class QuestionsConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'questions'
    verbose_name = 'Вопросы'
```

Comment: Спасибо! Все сработало.